# Entity classes have some issues while using retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-room, hashcode

I am getting this error while getting a response from an API.
Sometimes, it works fine but 8/10 times it crashes and shows me this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.newsapi.db.Entities.Source.hashCode(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.example.newsapi.db.Entities.Article.hashCode(Unknown Source:50)
```

This is the Article entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "Article_Table")
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int?=null,
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val description: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val source: Source,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String
): Serializable
```

This is the Source class declared in the Article class

```
data class Source(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)
```

Here is where I'm trying to put that Article object inside a Bundle

```
setOnClickListener {
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putSerializable("article", currentArticle)
    }
    when (from) {
    "BreakingNewsFragment" -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment, bundle)
    "SearchNewsFragment" -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_searchNewsFragment_to_articleFragment, bundle)
    "SavedNewsFragment" -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_savedNewsFragment_to_articleFragment, bundle)
    }
}
```

Here is the API call function

```
        @GET("v2/top-headlines")
        suspend fun getBreakingNews(
                @Query("country")
                countryCode: String = "us",
                @Query("page")
                pageNumber : Int = 1,
                @Query("apiKey")
                apiKey: String = API_KEY
        ): Response<NewsResponse>
```

calling that function from the repository

```
suspend fun getBreakingNews(countryCode: String, pageNumber: Int): Response<NewsResponse> {
        return RetrofitInstance.api.getBreakingNews(
                countryCode = countryCode,
                pageNumber = pageNumber
        )
}
```

calling that repository function from the viewmodel

```
fun getBreakingNews(countryCode: String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
                val response = articleRepository.getBreakingNews(countryCode, breakingNewsPage)
                breakingNews.postValue(handleBreakingNewsResponse(response))
        }
}
```

Here is the NewsResponse Class

```
data class NewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)
```

Comment: Please, let me know if I should add some additional information.

Comment: You did not show where you are making the API call in your code.  But make sure you make the response nullable, as your API may not always return a definite/expected response.

Comment: I added the API calls. But I'm using retrofit for the first time. Don't know how would I handle an unexpected response.

Comment: Please show the structure of NewsResponse.  Also, set default values for your entities fields or make the fields in your entities nullable; depending on your API response, some of the fields might not be available in what the API sends to you.

Comment: Good to know. You're welcome.

Comment: @ImrulAnwar What was the solution?